# How are indices written and managed when working with matrices and tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, kronecker-delta

I am watching a youtube series on tensors called Tensors for Beginners by eigenchris, and while I understand how things like backward and forward transformations for matrices, linear maps, basis vector, covectors, and components are derived, I don't understand the system that is being used to label indices. Take for example the steps to derive the backward transformation for a linear map (and forgive me for not formatting this, but I have no idea how to write all these symbols in text):
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeKbr.png)

What do the top and bottom indices mean? Why is the forward transformation for the linear map labeled with an l on the top, and an i on the bottom, but the backward transformation is labeled with an s on top and a t at the bottom. And then why is the original linear map labeled with a k and a j? Then how come when we cancel out the forward and backward transformations using the Kronecker delta, the opposite transformation being paired with the one in the original equation is labeled using different indices. What do these new indices represent? Several indices of new letters are added throughout the steps, but I don't get the logic behind how they are added and what they mean, and it's confusing me.

Comment: From my limited understanding, could it be the example is trying to remain non-specific on purpose? I managed to follow the formalism - are $F$ and $B$ commutable under multiplication?

Comment: @Threnody $F$ and $B$ are inverses of each other, so they do commute, but the relation between them is far closer than merely commuting.  They are change-of-basis matrices in opposite directions.

Comment: I think the OP should be more clear in the question about where the video series can be seen, since the notation used there is not always standard. For example, the forward and backward transformations in the series are introduced in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdCmW5N1LW4&list=PLJHszsWbB6hrkmmq57lX8BV-o-YIOFsiG&index=3

Comment: @Threnody I believe so only because they are inverses, but at the left-hand side, all these symbols function under the rules of linearity, and matrices themselves are not commutable. So let v and w be vectors, L(v+w) = Lv + Lw, and L(nv) = nL(v), which are the addition and scaling rules that also apply to covectors, and are called linearity. I think he is attempting to remain non-specific, but I am still having trouble understanding what the indices at the top and bottom are actually representing, and the ways in which they relate to each other.

Comment: In the video he is using the Eisenstein summation convention, so all summation symbols are being suppressed in the video clip you posted. The *generic* notation for the matrix of a linear map is $A = (a_{ij})$ where $Ae_j = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}e_i$.  Each new repeated set of indices  (one up and one down) is summed over. What is really going on is just the expression of the same linear transformation in two different bases. Have you studied linear algebra and bases of vector spaces already?

Comment: That makes sense to me. Apart from his series, the furthest I studied of linear algebra is basic operations on matrices and solving linear equations with them. I have a weak grasp of what bases of vector spaces are from the series, but that's about it.

Comment: The comment of KCd is on point. But the notation in the figure of the OP seems to consider also the so called Christoffel symbols which are used to  denote covariant and contravariant intices. They are quite common and good descriptions can be found in text on physics (Landau, 1951), differential geometry (Kreyszig,1991 - but I would avoid this one if you are new to it) and mechanics (Marsden,  Foundations of Mechanics).

Comment: @KCd. Not *Eisenstein* but *Einstein* (the physics guy!) summation convention.

Comment: Different authors have different systems for the indices. In physics it's common to use $a,b,c,\ldots$ for indices on tensors in ordinary 3-dimensional space and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$ for indices on tensors in 4-dimensional space-time.

Comment: Whether an index is upper or lower depends on how the tensor transforms in that index under change of coordinates.

Comment: @md2perpe that typo is a sign I am not a physicist. :)